# Want to remove Alt + Down arrow functionality for a cell not containing any data validation

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with lot of data entry fields. Some have dropdowns and I ise Alt+Down arrow to make selections. But for a cell not containing any Data Validation dropdown shows me the recently entered values in the same column if I press Alt+Down arrow.
Any way to stop this?
[image]

I don't want this suggestion box if I press Alt + Down in cell B6. 
Turning off Autofill didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you could do this for blank cells only, but you can disable the hotkey using VBA code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Disable()
    Application.OnKey "+^{DOWN}", ""
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Enable()
    Application.OnKey "+^{DOWN}"
End Sub
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that alt + up also opens the drop-down list, it's possible to do:

```
Private Sub Setup()
    Application.OnKey "%{DOWN}", "HandleAltDown"
End Sub

Private Sub HandleAltDown()
    If HasValidation(Application.ActiveCell) Then
        Application.SendKeys "%{UP}"
    End If
End Sub

Function HasValidation(cell As range) As Boolean
    Dim t: t = Null

    On Error Resume Next
    t = cell.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0

    HasValidation = Not IsNull(t)
End Function
```

It works pretty well. `HasValidation` was taken from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31346246/2862952

Comment: Interesting...I'll give it a try