# Warn if blank/empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to pop up a warning dialog if one of the cells in a range is blank.

Excel is popping up the warning when a cell is populated by a data validation drop down menu.

The code works on a range that doesn't contain data validation drop downs.

All data are strings and the cells are formatted as "General".

```
ActiveSheet.Range("I3:I10").Select
For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        If MsgBox("Customer information missing.  Okay to proceed; Cancel to stop and fill in missing information.", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The issue seems to stem from cells being merged across multiple columns, so Excel is checking each cell I3:K10 and finding J3:K10 blank. Unmerging the cells isn't an option.

Comment: You can try to replace your (="") with (<>"*") or (=vbNull)

Comment: A value added via a validation list should behave the same way as if you'd typed in the value directly, so if you see a value but the VBA reports the cell is empty then something else is going on.

Comment: There a `COUNTBLANK` worksheet formula you can use on the worksheet or directly in VBA with `Application.WorksheetFormula.`

Comment: I'll bet that your code is not looking at the workbook that you think it is...  See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1)

Comment: @Profex it's the only workbook open (and I can see the selected range when I step through the code), so I doubt it's looking anywhere else.

Comment: Add this on the line before the message `Debug.Print "'[" & Cell.Parent.Parent.Name & "]" & Cell.Parent.Name & "'!" & Cell.Address  "= """ & Cell.Value & """"`

Comment: @urdearboy the =vbNull worked for my initial issue, but created a new problem: blank cells aren't being detected now!

Comment: @Profex before the if statement containing the message box?  If so, it doesn't seem to do anything.  My warning still pops up when it isn't supposed to, but I don't see a debug printout anywhere.

Comment: in the VBE show the debug window by clicking `View->Immediate Window (Ctrl+G)`

Comment: @Profex okay, I see now.  It looks like the code is referencing column J instead of column I.  The cells are merged across I, J, and K, and I have seen that cause weird behavior before.  Unmerging the cells isn't really an option in this case, so I'll have to look for a workaround.  Thank you for helping identify the problem!

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense now...drop the select and it will work.  The selection is actuall `Range("I3:K10")`.  So after it checks column I it moves onto Column `J` and then `K`

Comment: @Profex perfect!  Doing it without selecting the cells works perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was wrong with my initial guess, but the cure still would've worked.

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1)

The selection is actually Range("I3:K10"). So after it checks column `I` it moves onto Column `J` and then `K`

Answer (score 1):

If a cell is set up with data validation using a list and one of the cells in the list range is blank, the cell will be considered blank even if the user has selected the blank cell from the drop-down. However, if you also want to check if the cell is empty *and* does not have data validation, you can use the following (thanks to [Determine if cell contains data validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642930/determine-if-cell-contains-data-validation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))

```
Dim blnValidation As Boolean
Dim cell As Range

ActiveSheet.Range("I3:I10").Select

For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        blnValidation = False

        On Error Resume Next
            blnValidation = Not IsNull(cell.Validation.Type)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not blnValidation Then
            If MsgBox("Customer information missing.  Okay to proceed; Cancel to stop and fill in missing information.", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I still get the same improper popup when the cell isn't blank.  >.<  There are only two choices in the drop down, and no blanks in the validation range.

Answer (score 0):

There a [`COUNTBLANK`](https://support.office.com/article/countblank-function-6a92d772-675c-4bee-b346-24af6bd3ac22) function but in this case you're probably better off with the [`COUNT` Application.WorksheetFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-count-method-excel).

You could replace your loop with:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("I3:I10")) < 8 Then
    'missing data - notify user here
End If
```

Comment: Still pops up my "missing data" warning even when all cells are populated.  :/

`For Each cell In Selection`
        `If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("I3:I10")) < 8 Then`
            `If MsgBox("Order processing information missing.  Okay to proceed; Cancel to stop and fill in missing information.", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then`
                `Exit Sub`
            `Else`
                `Exit For`
            `End If`
        `End If`
    `Next`