# VBA Code for selecting multiple drop down options not working on protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to allow multiple selections for in cell drop downs but the code stops working if I protect the sheet. Rather than adding a subsequent clicks separated by a comma, it just replaces the original selection.

The Target cells are not locked, yet it still isn't working. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Target.Column) = "MS" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "isn't working" is not a useful description of what happens when your code runs.  Where and how does it fail?  Note you may need to comment out the error handler to debug your problem.

Comment: Apologies. It works as regular cell validation and just replaces the original choice rather than adding a second one.

Comment: If you comment out `On Error GoTo Exitsub` you will see the problem - you ca't use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)` on a protected sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work on a protected sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Oldvalue As String, Newvalue As String

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Me.Cells(3, Target.Column) <> "MS" Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo Exitsub
    If HasValidation(Target) Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        ElseIf InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function HasValidation(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim t: t = Null

    On Error Resume Next
    t = cell.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0

    HasValidation = Not IsNull(t)
End Function
```

Function is from AgentRev's answer here:
[Determine if cell contains data validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642930/determine-if-cell-contains-data-validation)