Disable automatic updating of references in Excel using VBA
I am writing some macros in VBA for an Excel document, that uses a data base stored in 2 Worksheets, named "Datenbank" and "Stapler". Here is some data stored.
This 2 Worksheets are additionally stored in another Workbook stored in a server.
There is a Worksheet in the Excel document, that calculate things using references from this 2 Worksheets used as the database. This calculations are of the type:
= IF( F5 <> ""; XLOOKUP(F5; Stapler!B:B; Stapler!F:F; ""; 0); "")
or
= IF( X5 <> "";  X5 * XLOOKUP(H5; Datenbank!F:F; Datenbank!H:H; 0; 0) / 1000; 0)
The data base should be updatable from the server and you can just replace the existing worksheets "Datenbank" and "Stapler" with the new ones. The problem is, the references in the cells turn to "!REF#" (Error referencing) the moment you delete the old worksheets to replace them with the new updated ones, although the new ones have the exact same name and the old ones do not exist anymore.
I assume this happens because Excel references the objects and not just their names, but if I could turn off this automatic update of references or do something to change the existing references to the new worksheets, it would be awesome.
I have tried to change all formulas with Replace in Formula for all "UsedRange", but that takes too long and also it doesn't change the references made in some list dropdowns from data validation that also takes values from these 2 problematic worksheets.
Sub ImportDatenbankFunc()

' This Macro is responsible for the import of the Datenbank

    Dim Opfer1 As String, Opfer2 As String, Path As String, DatenbankPath As String, Version As String
    Dim Datenbank As Workbook, Rechner As Workbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Opfer1 = "Datenbank"
    Opfer2 = "Stapler"
    
    ' Delete the existing worksheets where Data is stored
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Opfer1).Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Opfer2).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Path of server where the new/updated version of the Data is stored
    Path = Dir("/Volumes/Topix-AFP/0 - Dateianhänge/Förderrechner/")
    Set Rechner = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Do While Path <> ""
    ' While the Path isnt empty (while there is still documents in the folder)
        If Left(Path, 9) = "Datenbank" Then
            ' If the first 9 letters of the document are "Datenbank", then open it
            DatenbankPath = "/Volumes/Topix-AFP/0 - Dateianhänge/Förderrechner/" & Path
            Set Datenbank = Workbooks.Open(DatenbankPath)
            Exit Do
        
        End If
        
        Path = Dir()
        
    Loop
    
    ' Copy the Worksheets"Datenbank" and "Stapler"
    Datenbank.Worksheets("Datenbank").Copy After:=Rechner.Sheets(Rechner.Sheets.count)
    Datenbank.Worksheets("Stapler").Copy After:=Rechner.Sheets(Rechner.Sheets.count)
    ' At this point, because there was no longer an existing "Datenbank" or "Stapler" Worksheets
    '  the new ones do not have the "(2)" after the name
    ' Read the version of the datenbank and write it down in a cell of "Versionierung"
    Version = Datenbank.Name
    Version = Right(Version, Len(Version) - 11)
    Version = Left(Version, Len(Version) - 5)
    Rechner.Worksheets("Versionierung").Range("I5").Value = Version
    Datenbank.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

' Attempt to dereference all cells, takes too long and doesnt dereference Data validation lists

Sub DeReference()

    Const RechnerWS As String = "Rechner (2)"
    Const OldRefStap As String = "Stapler"
    Const NewRefStap As String = "'Stapler (2)'"
    Const OldRefDB As String = "Datenbank"
    Const NewRefDB As String = "'Datenbank (2)'"

    Dim Zelle As Range
    For Each Zelle In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(RechnerWS).UsedRange.Cells
    
        Zelle.Formula = Replace(Zelle.Formula, OldRefStap, NewRefStap)
        Zelle.Formula = Replace(Zelle.Formula, OldRefDB, NewRefDB)
        
    Next Zelle

End Sub

I have also looked for a similar approach using Replace for the formula of the Dropdown list, but haven´t found anything. In a worst-case scenario, this would also be helpful.

Instead of deleting the sheets and replacing them, why not clear the data from the sheets and replace it with the new data?

You don't need to replace the sheets - you can instead replace the content.
For example:
Sub ImportDatenbankFunc()

    'use Const for fixed values
    Const FLDR As String = "/Volumes/Topix-AFP/0 - Dateianhänge/Förderrechner/"
    Const Opfer1 As String = "Datenbank"
    Const Opfer2 As String = "Stapler"
    
    Dim Path As String, DatenbankPath As String, Version As String, wsName, LastUsedCell As Range
    Dim Datenbank As Workbook, Rechner As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    
    Set Rechner = ActiveWorkbook
    
    ' Path of server where the new/updated version of the Data is stored
    Path = Dir(FLDR & "Datenbank*.xl*") 'use wildcard for file name
    If Len(Path) > 0 Then
        OptimizePerf True
        DatenbankPath = FLDR & Path
        Set Datenbank = Workbooks.Open(DatenbankPath)
    Else
        MsgBox "No source file found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'copy over sheet content
    For Each wsName In Array(Opfer1, Opfer2)
        Set wsSrc = Datenbank.Worksheets(wsName)
        Set wsDest = Rechner.Worksheets(wsName)
        
        wsDest.UsedRange.Clear
        Set LastUsedCell = LastCell(wsSrc)
        wsSrc.Range("A1", LastUsedCell).Copy wsDest.Range("A1")
    Next wsName
    
    ' Read the version of the datenbank and write it down in a cell of "Versionierung"
    Version = Datenbank.Name  '### consider using Mid() here...
    Version = Right(Version, Len(Version) - 11)
    Version = Left(Version, Len(Version) - 5)
    Rechner.Worksheets("Versionierung").Range("I5").Value = Version
    Datenbank.Close savechanges:=False
    
    OptimizePerf False 'undo settings changes

End Sub

'find the last cell with content on `ws`
Function LastCell(ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim fR As Range, fC As Range
    Set fR = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Not fR Is Nothing Then
        Set fC = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        Set LastCell = ws.Cells(fR.Row, fC.Column)
    End If
End Function

'enable/disable settings
Function OptimizePerf(Optional goFaster As Boolean = True)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(goFaster, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not goFaster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not goFaster
End Function


Thanks a lot, I also tested this answer and it also solves the problem. I was a little afraid, that the references on the dropdown lists would go crazy, but it also works like a charm and it is definitely less cumbersome than my solution. I have to do this for MacOs, so the Wildcards are a No-Go for me, but excluding this part, it works.

After working a little bit more, I think to have gotten it. Here is my complete answer. I have tested it and it also works. I would still be curious to see if anybody comes with a different answer:
Sub ImportDatenbankFunc()

' This Macro is responsible for the import of the Datenbank

    Dim Opfer1 As String, Opfer2 As String, Path As String, DatenbankPath As String, Version As String
    Dim Datenbank As Workbook, Rechner As Workbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Opfer1 = "Datenbank"
    Opfer2 = "Stapler"
    
    ' Path of server where the new/updated version of the Data is stored
    Path = Dir("/Volumes/Topix-AFP/0 - Dateianhänge/Förderrechner/")
    Set Rechner = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Do While Path <> ""
    ' While the Path isntempty (while there is still documents in the folder)
        If Left(Path, 9) = "Datenbank" Then
            ' If the first 9 letters of the document are "Datenbank"
            DatenbankPath = "/Volumes/Topix-AFP/0 - Dateianhänge/Förderrechner/" & Path
            Set Datenbank = Workbooks.Open(DatenbankPath)
            Exit Do
        
        End If
        
        Path = Dir()
        
    Loop
    
    ' Copy the Worksheets"Datenbank" and "Stapler"
    Datenbank.Worksheets("Datenbank").Copy After:=Rechner.Sheets(Rechner.Sheets.count)
    Datenbank.Worksheets("Stapler").Copy After:=Rechner.Sheets(Rechner.Sheets.count)
    
    DeReference
    
    ' Delete the existing worksheets where Data is stored
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Opfer1).Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Opfer2).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Rename new database worksheets
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Datenbank (2)").Name = "Datenbank"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stapler (2)").Name = "Stapler"
    
    ' Read the version of the datenbank and write it down in a cell of "Versionierung"
    Version = Datenbank.Name
    Version = Right(Version, Len(Version) - 11)
    Version = Left(Version, Len(Version) - 5)
    Rechner.Worksheets("Versionierung").Range("I5").Value = Version
    Datenbank.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub DeReference()

    Const RechnerWS As String = "Rechner"
    Const OldRefStap As String = "Stapler"
    Const NewRefStap As String = "'Stapler (2)'"
    Const OldRefDB As String = "Datenbank"
    Const NewRefDB As String = "'Datenbank (2)'"
    
    Dim temp As String
    Dim Zelle As Range
    
    For Each Zelle In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(RechnerWS).UsedRange.Cells
    
        Zelle.Formula = Replace(Zelle.Formula, OldRefStap, NewRefStap)
        Zelle.Formula = Replace(Zelle.Formula, OldRefDB, NewRefDB)
        
        If HasValidation(Zelle) = True Then
        
            temp = Zelle.Validation.Formula1
            
            If Left(temp, 9) <> "=INDIRECT" Then
        
                temp = Replace(temp, OldRefStap, NewRefStap)
                temp = Replace(temp, OldRefDB, NewRefDB)
                Zelle.Validation.Modify Formula1:=temp
            
            End If
        
        End If
        
    Next Zelle

End Sub

Function HasValidation(cell As Range) As Boolean

' Function to check if a Cell has validation (dropdown list)

    Dim t: t = Null

    On Error Resume Next
    t = cell.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0

    HasValidation = Not IsNull(t)
    
End Function



I have used the function "HasValidation" from another answer on another question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31346246/25525291). It doesn't take that long, when you turn off the screen update, change the calculation to manual and turn off events. In the sub DeReference I had to add a test if the Validation is an Indirect one, because for some reason, if the Validation is indirect, the macro just won't run and throws and error if you try to replace something. Hope somebody finds this helpful.
